# SQL - Removing starting html elements from post_content using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I am creating a wordpress site and have imported products from a previous site, however most of these products have a series of div and table tags at the beginning (and the closing tags at the end). For example:

```
<div align="center">
    <div id="innerwrapper">
    <div id="canvas" style="width: auto; padding: 1%; margin-left: autopx; margin-right: autopx; auto 0px; background: #E3F9FF; border-radius: 5px 25px 5px; box-shadow: #888888 0px 0px 1.25em;" align="center">
    &nbsp;
        <table style="width: 90%; margin-left: 3px; margin-right: 3px; align: center;">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    <div align="center">
                    <div id="innerwrapper">
                    <div id="canvas" style="width: auto; padding: 3%; background: #ffffff; border-radius: 25px; box-shadow: #888888 0px 0px 0em; text-align: center;" align="top">

{Product Information}

</div>
</div>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

As I am only after the {Product Information} section (which generally, but not always starts with a h2 tag, and has not standard ended), I am guessing that for the beginning of this I can use:

```
UPDATE `wp_posts`
SET `post_content = RIGHT(`post_content`,LENGTH(`post_content`)-INSTR(`post_content`,'<div id="canvas" style="width: auto; padding: 3%; background: #ffffff; border-radius: 25px; box-shadow: #888888 0px 0px 0em; text-align: center;" align="top">')-158)
WHERE `post_content` LIKE '%<div id="canvas" style="width: auto; padding: 3%; background: #ffffff; border-radius: 25px; box-shadow: #888888 0px 0px 0em; text-align: center;" align="top">%'
```

As this will find the last opening Div tag and take the content from the right. However, I cannot figure out the closing tags as there are  through the product information and there is an occassional inclusion of text after the last  and a 
/  every so often.

My questions I guess is, can I get the index/instr of the end closing tags even through I would need to use wildcards to get the majority of them?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Hi Tim, I am running 5.1.73

Answer (score 0):

Check does this code is applicable to your MySQL version:

```
UPDATE wp_posts
SET post_content = TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(post_content, 'align="top">', -1), '</div>', 1))
WHERE `post_content` LIKE '%align="top">%'
```

I have shortened the marker pattern to `'align="top">'` - but you may extend it back if needed. And I have used `'</div>'` as finalizing marker - alter if needed.